# DPLYR error: argument is not interpretable as logical

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, bioinformatics

I want to subset **glioma** samples as `scf.glioma` dataframe from the `scf` dataframe by removing any columns that begin with **NB**, which is saved as `scf.control`. I tried to use the `select` function in the `dplyr` library to filter out any `scf.control` samples from the `scf` dataframe but it produced an error : argument is not interpretable as logical.

```
library(dplyr)
scf.ann <- ann[ann$Gene.symbol=="KITLG",]
scf <- dat.filtered[rownames(dat.filtered) %in% rownames(scf.ann),]
scf.control <- scf %>% select(starts_with("NB"))
scf.glioma <- select(scf, -one_of(colnames(scf.control)) %>% colnames(scf))
```

> Error: argument is not interpretable as logical Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. In addition:
> Warning message: In if (do.NULL) NULL else if (nc > 0L) paste0(prefix,
> seq_len(nc)) else character() :   the condition has length > 1 and
> only the first element will be used

```
scf.glioma <- as.numeric(unlist(scf.glioma))
```

> ```
> > dput(scf)
> structure(list(NB_GSM97800 = c(116.2, 5.5, 2.8, 1867.7), NB_GSM97803 = c(72.8, 
> 29, 2.7, 1321.4), NB_GSM97804 = c(89.5, 18.1, 5, 1275.8), NB_GSM97805 = c(58.6, 
> 27.4, 4.4, 1226), NB_GSM97807 = c(71, 28.4, 0.8, 1431.1), NB_GSM97809 = c(62.7, 
> 39.5, 1, 863.2), NB_GSM97811 = c(97.5, 82.7, 5.8, 1458.4), NB_GSM97812 = c(116.9, 
> 80, 5.4, 1627.5), NB_GSM97816 = c(9.8, 10.5, 3.6, 470.5), NB_GSM97817 = c(148.9, 
> 18.8, 10.1, 1224.8), NB_GSM97820 = c(121.1, 76.3, 5.6, 1192.6
> ), NB_GSM97825 = c(128, 83.1, 2.5, 1724.6), NB_GSM97827 = c(157.6, 
> 101.2, 2.5, 1927.2), NB_GSM97828 = c(60.3, 5.8, 2.4, 425.2), 
>     NB_GSM97833 = c(111.6, 84.3, 1.8, 1346.4), NB_GSM97834 = c(62.1, 
>     29.1, 1.7, 1443.2), NB_GSM97840 = c(67, 84.1, 2.3, 1126.4
>     ), NB_GSM97846 = c(131.3, 45.3, 1.7, 1682.3), NB_GSM97848 = c(116.3, 
>     28.7, 11.5, 1516), NB_GSM97849 = c(141.7, 105.6, 1.7, 1854.9
>     ), NB_GSM97850 = c(97.3, 62.6, 6, 1272.7), NB_GSM97853 = c(84.3, 
>     89, 42.1, 1551.1), NB_GSM97855 = c(56.6, 7, 5.2, 559.8), 
>     II_GSM97878 = c(88.7, 2.9, 14.7, 858), II_GSM97913 = c(184.4, 
>     73.5, 2.9, 1223.3), II_GSM97932 = c(81.6, 39.8, 42.8, 1802.5
>     ), II_GSM97939 = c(61.5, 11.6, 3.9, 462.4), II_GSM97951 = c(67.2, 
>     37.8, 3.5, 1165.8), II_GSM97957 = c(101.8, 5.3, 2.3, 669.1
>     ), II_GSM97972 = c(75.4, 30.7, 2.1, 1041.2), III_GSM97793 = c(203.2, 
>     44.2, 3.6, 2168.4), III_GSM97795 = c(90, 84.1, 3.3, 1338.6
>     ), III_GSM97802 = c(109.2, 3.3, 2.3, 206.5), III_GSM97810 = c(130.3, 
>     90.1, 1.9, 2442.2), III_GSM97815 = c(154, 46.1, 4.1, 1500.2
>     ), III_GSM97837 = c(164.6, 54.1, 2.6, 1630.4), III_GSM97843 = c(188.7, 
>     142.1, 2.5, 1523.7), III_GSM97890 = c(60.2, 7, 5.2, 566.8
>     ), III_GSM97899 = c(127.8, 11.1, 2, 1796.6), III_GSM97910 = c(28, 
>     2.6, 1.8, 1433.3), III_GSM97916 = c(138.6, 79.3, 1.3, 1326.7
>     ), III_GSM97920 = c(16.7, 13.9, 2.1, 495.1), III_GSM97921 = c(181.6, 
>     107.1, 3.5, 2362.4), III_GSM97927 = c(81.6, 66, 1, 1127), 
>     III_GSM97937 = c(78.6, 51.4, 1.2, 1382), III_GSM97941 = c(177.5, 
>     52.1, 71.8, 1301.9), III_GSM97943 = c(70.1, 41.7, 3.5, 1822.6
>     ), III_GSM97958 = c(167.8, 56.4, 10.2, 1789.2), III_GSM97960 = c(49.6, 
>     36.9, 4.2, 1210), IV_GSM97794 = c(186.2, 152.3, 6, 1671.8
>     ), IV_GSM97796 = c(189.9, 122.4, 3.2, 1539.2), IV_GSM97797 = c(196.6, 
>     100.8, 1.1, 963.7), IV_GSM97798 = c(367.8, 308.4, 1.4, 2131
>     ), IV_GSM97801 = c(132.1, 12, 3.1, 955.1), IV_GSM97806 = c(191.8, 
>     95.6, 4.8, 1085.6), IV_GSM97808 = c(145.1, 151.5, 21, 2052.2
>     ), IV_GSM97813 = c(146.6, 89.3, 1, 1103.9), IV_GSM97814 = c(224.4, 
>     78.6, 2.9, 1890.6), IV_GSM97818 = c(40.7, 11.6, 1.7, 1737.7
>     ), IV_GSM97819 = c(200.9, 106.9, 2, 1504.8), IV_GSM97821 = c(152.6, 
>     94, 2.5, 1180), IV_GSM97826 = c(67.6, 47.4, 22.7, 810.3), 
>     IV_GSM97829 = c(103.1, 61.5, 1.4, 1609.4), IV_GSM97832 = c(76.1, 
>     28, 2.2, 1281.6), IV_GSM97836 = c(133.3, 43.1, 2.5, 1257.7
>     ), IV_GSM97839 = c(121.2, 73.9, 1.8, 1756.5), IV_GSM97844 = c(135, 
>     82.5, 6.6, 1624.8), IV_GSM97847 = c(137.7, 41.4, 5.7, 1080.4
>     ), IV_GSM97851 = c(151.8, 140, 1.4, 1668.9), IV_GSM97852 = c(96.4, 
>     118.2, 4.3, 830.6), IV_GSM97856 = c(160, 44.8, 19.4, 1824.3
>     ), IV_GSM97858 = c(102.4, 9.3, 4.5, 1254.7), IV_GSM97859 = c(118.5, 
>     27.8, 3.7, 577.7), IV_GSM97861 = c(181.2, 119.8, 4.4, 2091.7
>     ), IV_GSM97863 = c(168.9, 77.9, 2.2, 1578.3), IV_GSM97869 = c(99.1, 
>     67.5, 2.9, 984.3), IV_GSM97870 = c(81.9, 52.5, 4.3, 914.6
>     ), IV_GSM97871 = c(142.6, 132.3, 2.6, 1445.3), IV_GSM97877 = c(85.6, 
>     65.9, 3.4, 1508.7), IV_GSM97879 = c(56.8, 13.9, 1.3, 1456.5
>     ), IV_GSM97882 = c(153.8, 91.6, 2, 876.2), IV_GSM97885 = c(81.1, 
>     106.5, 1, 1240.7), IV_GSM97886 = c(66.1, 13.9, 5.4, 780.6
>     ), IV_GSM97887 = c(111.4, 3.7, 4.4, 609.2), IV_GSM97888 = c(111.8, 
>     34.3, 3.7, 804.8), IV_GSM97889 = c(121, 78.6, 1.2, 1204.5
>     ), IV_GSM97891 = c(118.4, 8, 4.2, 1047), IV_GSM97892 = c(141.5, 
>     103, 40.1, 1186.8), IV_GSM97893 = c(145.6, 49.8, 2.6, 2324
>     ), IV_GSM97894 = c(143.6, 111.9, 8.1, 2007.1), IV_GSM97896 = c(118.3, 
>     41.4, 8.4, 1503.7), IV_GSM97898 = c(190.8, 178.3, 2.9, 2856.6
>     ), IV_GSM97903 = c(159.6, 45.2, 4.3, 1174.1), IV_GSM97905 = c(97.9, 
>     38.6, 3.7, 1422), IV_GSM97906 = c(110.4, 102, 1.5, 1360.6
>     ), IV_GSM97908 = c(76.7, 15.4, 4.4, 2207.8), IV_GSM97912 = c(43.6, 
>     6.8, 2.2, 778.1), IV_GSM97914 = c(95.3, 3.9, 1, 905.6), IV_GSM97915 = c(193.9, 
>     119.6, 5.5, 1666.4), IV_GSM97917 = c(802.8, 552, 3.5, 3560.7
>     ), IV_GSM97918 = c(131.5, 80.8, 3.1, 1964.2), IV_GSM97919 = c(262.6, 
>     254.8, 4.6, 1556), IV_GSM97922 = c(138.6, 67.5, 3.7, 770.5
>     ), IV_GSM97924 = c(99.8, 12.3, 4.1, 879), IV_GSM97926 = c(102.5, 
>     14.3, 1.8, 1142.9), IV_GSM97930 = c(70.6, 21.5, 4, 1740.5
>     ), IV_GSM97931 = c(130.9, 41.7, 23.8, 558.8), IV_GSM97935 = c(121.6, 
>     53.8, 1.6, 1180.3), IV_GSM97936 = c(121.8, 79.1, 2.7, 1830.8
>     ), IV_GSM97938 = c(160.9, 109.4, 1.9, 1714.8), IV_GSM97940 = c(191.9, 
>     96.7, 2.5, 1562.9), IV_GSM97942 = c(211.2, 140.6, 5.4, 1276.2
>     ), IV_GSM97945 = c(108.8, 86.9, 1.8, 1329.3), IV_GSM97946 = c(87, 
>     47.3, 1.1, 1587.7), IV_GSM97948 = c(117.5, 42.7, 5.4, 778.6
>     ), IV_GSM97950 = c(260.6, 237.2, 6.9, 3320.4), IV_GSM97952 = c(248.7, 
>     166.3, 7.8, 1446.4), IV_GSM97953 = c(173.1, 88.4, 2.6, 5287.1
>     ), IV_GSM97954 = c(71.8, 49.4, 2.8, 1334.8), IV_GSM97955 = c(83.4, 
>     79.8, 21.1, 919.8), IV_GSM97959 = c(100.6, 52.2, 9.2, 1607.6
>     ), IV_GSM97961 = c(86.7, 25.8, 2.3, 1600.9), IV_GSM97963 = c(105.9, 
>     62.7, 1.2, 933), IV_GSM97965 = c(119.9, 77.2, 4.9, 1959.5
>     ), IV_GSM97966 = c(74.4, 50.9, 6.3, 804.2), IV_GSM97967 = c(56.9, 
>     28.6, 1.7, 2295), IV_GSM97968 = c(74.1, 9.4, 6.2, 1142.8), 
>     IV_GSM97969 = c(56, 67.1, 6.7, 1057.5), IV_GSM97971 = c(113.6, 
>     52.7, 1.2, 923.4), II_GSM97799 = c(197.5, 93.3, 22.6, 1552.4
>     ), II_GSM97823 = c(133.6, 8.7, 1.4, 1545.7), II_GSM97824 = c(66.1, 
>     52.9, 1.1, 2014), II_GSM97830 = c(91.2, 5.3, 3.3, 613.5), 
>     II_GSM97835 = c(109.5, 43.6, 1.9, 1556.4), II_GSM97838 = c(108.1, 
>     50.9, 3.4, 1515.2), II_GSM97841 = c(79.2, 89.3, 4, 2068.6
>     ), II_GSM97842 = c(149.1, 27.9, 1.4, 1190.1), II_GSM97854 = c(74.5, 
>     49.5, 4.4, 1121.1), II_GSM97857 = c(97.4, 10.7, 5.3, 1591.9
>     ), II_GSM97860 = c(150.3, 16.5, 14, 1937.4), II_GSM97862 = c(48.8, 
>     19.9, 3.7, 970.9), II_GSM97864 = c(108, 51, 26.3, 1659.9), 
>     II_GSM97866 = c(87.1, 99.9, 5, 1114.7), II_GSM97868 = c(113.6, 
>     50.7, 2.7, 780.5), II_GSM97872 = c(62.4, 23.5, 0.8, 856.3
>     ), II_GSM97873 = c(116.5, 42.8, 1.9, 884.9), II_GSM97874 = c(145.4, 
>     65.3, 2.9, 1653.4), II_GSM97875 = c(196.2, 83.8, 4.7, 1884.1
>     ), II_GSM97876 = c(138.2, 28.5, 2.9, 1599.9), II_GSM97880 = c(150.8, 
>     11.3, 15.1, 2020.6), II_GSM97881 = c(101, 66, 8.1, 919), 
>     II_GSM97884 = c(119, 62, 5.9, 2846.2), II_GSM97901 = c(98.8, 
>     2.9, 15.4, 1469.7), II_GSM97902 = c(80, 44.9, 7.2, 1638.8
>     ), II_GSM97909 = c(141.9, 66.6, 4.5, 984.5), II_GSM97911 = c(139.4, 
>     8.9, 33.4, 1045.6), II_GSM97923 = c(198.2, 81.6, 25.4, 1875.6
>     ), II_GSM97928 = c(80.1, 10.2, 14.2, 432.1), II_GSM97929 = c(97.8, 
>     104.4, 8, 2026.4), II_GSM97933 = c(99.2, 51.3, 1.6, 2814.5
>     ), II_GSM97934 = c(120.7, 46.4, 5.8, 2613.3), II_GSM97944 = c(116.6, 
>     65.9, 7.6, 1492.6), II_GSM97949 = c(104.2, 76.1, 6.9, 2139.2
>     ), II_GSM97956 = c(88.5, 7.1, 1, 1255.5), II_GSM97962 = c(56, 
>     5.2, 3.6, 807.8), II_GSM97964 = c(90.5, 42.6, 1.9, 986.8), 
>     II_GSM97970 = c(205.3, 80, 3, 1313.8), III_GSM97822 = c(85, 
>     53.1, 4.2, 562.7), III_GSM97831 = c(94.2, 39.8, 4.3, 2129.4
>     ), III_GSM97845 = c(147.7, 116.4, 1.1, 1918.8), III_GSM97865 = c(98.4, 
>     29.6, 7.1, 1588.5), III_GSM97867 = c(126.2, 21.2, 2.5, 1551.4
>     ), III_GSM97883 = c(53.4, 12.3, 1.3, 842.6), III_GSM97897 = c(133.6, 
>     49, 1.6, 740.4), III_GSM97900 = c(150.3, 30.6, 3.8, 832), 
>     III_GSM97904 = c(131.4, 13.8, 30.7, 2116.2), III_GSM97907 = c(87.4, 
>     114.3, 6.3, 1129.7), III_GSM97925 = c(83.5, 17.5, 2.9, 460.9
>     ), III_GSM97947 = c(103.7, 12.2, 2.2, 527.5)), row.names = c("207029_at", 
> "211124_s_at", "216974_at", "226534_at"), class = "data.frame")
> ```

---

> ```
> > dput(scf.control)
> structure(list(NB_GSM97800 = c(116.2, 5.5, 2.8, 1867.7), NB_GSM97803 = c(72.8, 
> 29, 2.7, 1321.4), NB_GSM97804 = c(89.5, 18.1, 5, 1275.8), NB_GSM97805 = c(58.6, 
> 27.4, 4.4, 1226), NB_GSM97807 = c(71, 28.4, 0.8, 1431.1), NB_GSM97809 = c(62.7, 
> 39.5, 1, 863.2), NB_GSM97811 = c(97.5, 82.7, 5.8, 1458.4), NB_GSM97812 = c(116.9, 
> 80, 5.4, 1627.5), NB_GSM97816 = c(9.8, 10.5, 3.6, 470.5), NB_GSM97817 = c(148.9, 
> 18.8, 10.1, 1224.8), NB_GSM97820 = c(121.1, 76.3, 5.6, 1192.6
> ), NB_GSM97825 = c(128, 83.1, 2.5, 1724.6), NB_GSM97827 = c(157.6, 
> 101.2, 2.5, 1927.2), NB_GSM97828 = c(60.3, 5.8, 2.4, 425.2), 
>     NB_GSM97833 = c(111.6, 84.3, 1.8, 1346.4), NB_GSM97834 = c(62.1, 
>     29.1, 1.7, 1443.2), NB_GSM97840 = c(67, 84.1, 2.3, 1126.4
>     ), NB_GSM97846 = c(131.3, 45.3, 1.7, 1682.3), NB_GSM97848 = c(116.3, 
>     28.7, 11.5, 1516), NB_GSM97849 = c(141.7, 105.6, 1.7, 1854.9
>     ), NB_GSM97850 = c(97.3, 62.6, 6, 1272.7), NB_GSM97853 = c(84.3, 
>     89, 42.1, 1551.1), NB_GSM97855 = c(56.6, 7, 5.2, 559.8)), row.names = c("207029_at", 
> "211124_s_at", "216974_at", "226534_at"), class = "data.frame")
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

To remove:

```
library(dplyr)
scf.glioma <- scf %>% 
    select(-starts_with("NB"))
```

To subset:

```
scf.control <- scf %>% 
    select(starts_with("NB"))
```

Comment: `scf.control <- scf %>% select(starts_with("NB"))` is now giving me a `Error in select(., starts_with("NB")) : 
  unused argument (starts_with("NB"))`

Comment: `library(dplyr)` if yes then `scf.control <- scf %>% 
    dplyr::select(starts_with("NB"))`

Comment: you should have your `scf` dataframe loaded. `scf <- structure(list(NB_GSM97800 = c(116.2, 5.5, 2.8, 1867.7), NB_GSM97803 = c(72.8, 
29, 2.7, 1321.4), NB_GSM97.............`

Comment: yes `scf.control <- scf %>%      dplyr::select(starts_with("NB"))` works. Thanks